# SQL query - Can I not do this?

Tags: sql-server

```
update TABLE set A = (
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN B - C >= A  THEN A
        WHEN B - C <  A THEN B - C
    END AS A
from 
TABLE )
```

The response I get is :

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: No, that won't work if your table has more than 1 record.

Comment: thanks @rsbarro. would it be possible to acheive that functionality with a single query?

Comment: please see my answer, is that what you're looking for? I don't see why you need to use a subquery.

Comment: @rsbarro yes. just saw the answer...you are correct. I dont need to use a subquery and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work if your table has more than 1 record. In this case, I'm not sure why you are using a subquery. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET A = 
    CASE
        WHEN B - C >= A THEN A
        ELSE B - C
    END
```

This query will update the column `A` for every record in the table. If `B - C` is greater than or equal to `A`, the value of `A` will be unchanged. Otherwise, `A` will be set to `B - C`. I would also use an `ELSE` instead of two `WHEN`s.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the second WHEN is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem you have here is that you do not specify the primary keys in the subquery to match the primary key of the row updated. Hence it returns all the rows matching the condition which is what the error message is referring to.

Probably your code should read:

```
UPDATE TableABC
SET A = CASE
          WHEN B - C >= A THEN A
          WHEN B - C <  A THEN B - C
        END
```

But your SQL being incomplete I cannot be sure.